# Can we change the contents of the tensors once it is used?

Tags: pytorch

I am wondering if we are allowed to change the contents of the tensors after they are sent to the Loss Functions in pytorch. For example:

```
x = torch.zeros(1000)
y = torch.zeros(1000)
output = net(x)

loss = criterion(oytput, y)
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

After we have done this, can we change the contents of `y` and `output` without ill-effect? For example:

```
y[0] = 990
output[0] = 1000
```

After I have done this after a mini-batch, but keep feeding it with more mini-batches, will this cause issues?

I am not so sure, because maybe the nodes are still referenced internally by the computational graph.

Comment: I don't think there will be a side effect here. After calling backward(), the graph actually doesn't exist. If you change the contents of the tensor, it will affect the new graph but doesn't affect previous results.

Comment: Also, the output is going to be overridden by the statement, `output = net(x)`. So, what is the point of setting `output[0] = 1000`?

Comment: I was thinking that maybe `pytorch` holds some references to variables internally and inadvertently changing them will cause unintended effects. Note that `backward` does have `retain_graph` and `create_graph` options and when they are enabled, chaning the variables might have an effect.